# Problema adicionar imagem dentro de uma Thread

Tags: android, imagem, thread

Tenho essa seguinte class chamada dentro da main está funcionando perfeitamente único problema é para eu setar a imagem que recebi na msg da o seguinte erro

> E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-201
>       android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

```
 class LooperThread extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {

      try {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("entro");
            Fila fila = new Fila("NocView", "NocView-Campainha", TipoFila.Get, "rabbit01.spacnet.com.br", "campainha", "campainha");
            byte[] teste = fila.consome();
            Mensagem m = new Mensagem().getObjeto(teste);
            Campainha campainha2 = (Campainha) m;
            fila.ack();


            InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(campainha2.getImagem());
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(in, "src name");

            byte[] data = campainha2.getImagem();
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(campainha2.getImagem(), 0, campainha2.getImagem().length);
            img.setImageBitmap(bmp);  -> erro

    }
}
```

como poderia estar resolvendo esse problema??

Comment: Não conheço muito de android, mas uma coisa que já vi em algumas linguagens é que alterar a UI via thread gera problemas. Geralmente pode-se notificar a main thread para realizar a mudança.

Comment: No Android você pode usar `AsyncTask` para implementar essas duas etapas (etapa 1: carregar os dados e etapa 2: atualizar o bitmap) nos métodos `doInBackground()` e `onPostExecute()` (o primeiro roda em um _thread_ secundário e o segundo no _thread_ principal, que é o _thread_ que pode atualizar a tela). Com isso você também evita criar uma subclasse de `Thread`, a `AsyncTask` já faz isso pra você por debaixo dos panos. Procure por exemplos no Google, como [este aqui](https://arthurlehdermann.wordpress.com/2013/03/11/asynctask-executando-tarefas-em-segundo-plano/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar uma AsyncTask e colocar a parte de manipulação da imagem dentro dela.

Se o processamento não for pesado, você pode usar uma UIThread, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
 [Sua Activity].this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                //procesamento aqui
            }
        });
```

Nesse caso, você precisa da sua Activity.